# How can i resize the parent view after changing the constraints of child views?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a pop up view which is loading from a `xib` file.In that file there are couple of views, labels and buttons. For specific condition i have hide couple of views and buttons and its working but total height of the parent view of those views and buttons is not changing.

I have set the height constraints of the parent view and tried to change the constant but its not updating.

```
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

I want to resize the parent view after hide the parent view.
[Main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cc6Z.png)
[Changed window after constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IoNr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the view does not remove it from its parents. It just changes its visibility. The view still remains in the hierarchy. To achieve what you want to do the following:

1. Constraint the view above and view below the view you want to hide with a lower priority.
2. remove the view(the one you want to hide) from its superview

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have solved this already and i have used your procedure and it works.